# Map Entity Framework collection to comma delimted string with automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a parent class:

```
public class Parent
{
    ...
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

Location class:

```
public class Location
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Destination class for mapping:

```
public class Destination
{
    ...
    public string DelimitedLocations { get; set; }
}
```

I need to map the LocationId list from Locations to a comma delimited string using automapper.

Here are several things I have tried:

```
CreateMap<Parent, Destination>().ForMember(d => d.DelimitedLocations , o => o.MapFrom(s => string.Join(",", s.Locations.ToList().Select(t => t.LocationID.ToString()))))
```

Result:
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Next attempt:

```
CreateMap<Parent, Destination>()..ForMember(d => d.TestPlotLocationsSelected, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.TestPlotLocations.ToList().Select(t => string.Join(",", t.TestPlotLocationID.ToString()))))
```

Result:
No method 'ToString' exists on type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]'.

Not sure what to try next.

Comment: It has nothing to do with AutoMapper - with or without it, you can't do what you want in LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: In the `set;` of your `DelimitedLocations`, you could try to just create a `StringBuilder` and a `foreach` and ultimately create what you want - that may be a lot easier..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I ended up populating the delimited property outside of the mapping.

Answer (score 3):

Select statement should be something like

```
o.Locations.Select(x => x.LocationId).ToList()
```

### Demo

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Initialize();

        var source = new Parent
        {
            Locations = new List<Location>
            {
                new Location {LocationId = 1, Name = "One"},
                new Location {LocationId = 2, Name = "Two"},
                new Location {LocationId = 3, Name = "Three"},
            }
        };

        var destination = Mapper.Map<Parent, Destination>(source);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        MapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Parent, Destination>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.DelimitedLocations, mo => mo.MapFrom(src =>
                    src.Locations != null
                        ? string.Join(",", src.Locations.Select(x => x.LocationId).ToList())
                        : ""));
        });
        Mapper = MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
    }

    public static IMapper Mapper { get; private set; }

    public static MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration { get; private set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public string DelimitedLocations { get; set; }
}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: This is similar to my first attempt. However, my Location list is an Entity Framework collection. LINQ to Entities doesn't like string.Join. See the error message I got for my first attempt.

Comment: Yes, I tried your answer and I get this error: Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[xxx.xxx.Location, xxx.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.

Comment: Error might not be in AutoMapper. Does your Entity Framework even work before mapping?

Comment: You are correct, this isn't an automapper issue. I just happened to find it while trying to use automapper. All of my other mapping is working when I leave this one out. I decided to not spend anymore time trying to force this mapping to work. I can populate simply after the mapping is done. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: Ideally, we call `ToList()` before mapping, so that results are queried to memory. For example, `_dbContext.Parent.Include("Location").ToList()`